# Get -WinEvent - Reading From a Saved Event Log File

Tags: powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

Easy question, I have the following that reads the application log:

```
$out = @()
$endtime=[datetime]::Today
$starttime=    $endtime.AddDays(-10)
$evts = get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{ logname="application"; Level= "1","2"; starttime=    $starttime;endtime=    $endtime } -maxevents 10 | select TimeCreated, Providername, id,Message
foreach(    $evt in     $evts){
$mess = RemoveBlankSpaces(    $evt.Message)
$out += "    $(    $evt.ID),    $(    $evt.Providername),    $(    $evt.TimeCreated),    $mess"
}
  $out | out-file -filepath .\warning.txt
```

How do you get it to read from a evtx file (a saved event log file)?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

```
Get-WinEvent -Path C:\SavedAppLog.evtx
```

Comment: Thanks; but that doesn't filter on a date range, or event sources, and the messages get truncated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a path to the request as below:

```
$evts = get-winevent -FilterHashtable @{path="c:\mylogpath" logname="application"; Level= "1","2"; starttime = $starttime; endtime = $endtime } -maxevents 10 | select TimeCreated, Providername, id, Message
```

BTW, I was searching for a way to export certain events to a summary log file. Your script helped me do that so thanks!  :)